# Incorrectly adding a line to a txt file

Tags: python-3.x, file, addition

For some reason, when writing a string to a file in "a" mode, the necessary (conditional) string is added 125 times. Although one entry is obviously enough for me. 
And if you start adding in the "w" mode, then, respectively, the loop will add only the last checked line to the file each time, while clearing the previous one. 
How can I fix the addition via "a" mode?

```
workbook = open('base.txt')
print('Starting...')

count = 0
for line in workbook:
    number = (str(line)[0:11])


    with open(r"base.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    del lines[0]
    with open(r"base.txt", "w") as file:
        file.writelines(lines)

    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            pix = rgb.getpixel((x, y))
        if pix in color:

           with open('checkbase.txt', 'a') as filehandle:
                filehandle.write(line) #125 times add

    print(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added your file appending operation in 'for' cycle. Your code should look something like this

```
for x in range(img.size[0]):
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        pix = rgb.getpixel((x, y))
    if pix in color:
        result = '{cyan}YEAH{endcolor}'.format(cyan='\033[96m', endcolor='\033[0m')

with open('checkbase.txt', 'a') as filehandle:
    filehandle.write(line)  # appending file should now happen only once for every line
```

When using 'w' mode for opening files, it overrides file content every time you open file, so you had only one record because it not only created, but also deleted 124 old records

Comment: But in this case, it adds absolutely all the numbers to the new file. Including those that do not meet the condition. @Alexey

Comment: @JohnTit, please, give example of base.txt file.

Comment: Just phone numbers, @Alexey

Comment: @JohnTit, as far, as i see, you check each pixel of an image and if that pixel has appropriate color, you append current phone number to the "checkbase.txt" file, but there can be multiple pixels of appropriate color, so your number is added multiple times.

Comment: Really. All right. But is there a way to fix the addition, by avoiding the removal of conditions on pixels? @Alexey

Comment: @JohnTit, I'm not sure, how you want it to work, but you can add `break` after first successful appending to the file. Hope it will help

Comment: Yes, it helped. I am not sure of the reliability of such a solution, but at least so. Thank you very much. @Alexey